# How to only play animation while a sprite is moving in Phaser 3?

Tags: animation, game-physics, phaser-framework, matter.js

I'm creating a game in Phaser 3, using the matter physics, as I've done before. A problem I've never run into until now, however, involves animations and movement. I want my animation to only play while the player is moving, and stop when he stops moving, like a player would in a real game.

I've tried all sorts of do-while loops, using `"animationcomplete"` and without it. I've also tried having my animation on loop (`repeat: -1`) and having it set to only execute once.

I DO know that, `.isDown` tracks the key and does the following code as long as it as pressed, versus `.JustDown` only executing it once. I'm not really sure which to use there either.

Code for animation

```js
 //Animations
 //Running right animation
 var runRightFrameNames = this.anims.generateFrameNames('sheet', {
    start: 14,
    end: 16,
    zeroPad: 4,
    prefix: 'run_right/'
 })
 
 this.anims.create({
    key: 'runRight',
    frames: runRightFrameNames,
    frameRate: 1,
    repeat: 0
 })
```

Current code inside `update()` function, not the only thing I've tried

```js
//If the right arrowkey is pressed
   if (this.arrowKeys.right.isDown) {
      //Move player
      this.hero.setVelocityX(5);
      //Play animation
      this.hero.anims.play('runRight');
      //When animation is done, stop hero
      this.hero.on("animationcomplete", () => {
      this.hero.setVelocityX(0);
   });
}
```

Comment: I saw your message, yeah I understand what you need. It seems that with Matter physics is harder to get that working. I'll keep digging.

Comment: @ManuelAbascal understood. I’ll keep digging through forums and such as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your code snippet like this:

```js
//If the right arrowkey is pressed
if (this.arrowKeys.right._justDown) {
    console.log('Cursor right is pressed!');
    
    //Move player
    this.hero.setVelocityX(5);
 
    //Play animation
    this.hero.anims.play('runRight');

} else if (this.arrowKeys.right._justUp) {
    console.log('Cursor right is NOT pressed!');
}
```

**EDIT:**

To fix the hero's animation change this line **`this.hero.anims.play('runRight');`** to **`this.hero.anims.play('runRight', true);`**

You should also change the **`repeat`** value to **`-1`** like so:

```js
this.anims.create({
    key: 'runRight', frames: runRightFrameNames, frameRate: 6, repeat: -1
});
```

Comment: I wanted to share this with you. I'll try to fix the animation tomorrow!

Comment: Thank you, I will too. Progress is progress

Comment: You can go to sleep, I’m about to do the same. I’ll sort everything out in the morning if that’s okay